# Validação de IP's sem atualizar a página

Tags: php, jquery

Criei uma ferramenta para me ajudar a testar minhas listas de proxy, ela testa proxy por proxy e **printa** na tela o resultado pra min, porem não esta printando somente os resultado mais também esta **printando** o `textarea` que uso para colocar os `proxys` que são testados como posso arrumar isso ?

```
<html>

<head>
<title> testar ips </title>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
      function enviar(){
        var bin = $("#bin_id").val();
        var linhaenviar = bin.split("\n");
        var index = 0;
        linhaenviar.forEach(function(value){

          setTimeout(

            function(){
              $.ajax({
                url: 'index.php',
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'html',
                data: "bin=" + value,
                success: function(resultado){
                  document.write(resultado + "<br>");
              }
            })

          }, 10 * index);

        index = index + 3;

        })
      }
  </script>

</head>
<body>
<center>
<textarea name="ip" id="ip_id" rows="10" cols="40">
</textarea>
<br>
<input type="button" value="testar ips" onclick="enviar();"></input>
</center>
</body>
</html>


<?php


error_reporting(0);

 if ($_POST['ip']) {
    $bin = substr($_POST['ip'], 0, 90);

            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "fonte dps testes");
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
            curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "input_proxy=$ip" );
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
            $s = curl_exec($ch);
            $pop = preg_match( '/<p>(.*)<\/p>/si' , $s , $match);


$vdd = ' ';

if($pop >= "1") 

{ $vdd = "<b><font color='red'>#DIE_IPS </font></b>"; } 

else { $vdd = "<b><font color='green'>#LIVE_IPS </font></b>"; }


 $tudo = " [".$ip." ".$vdd."] ";


 echo "<br><br><center>".$vdd." ".$ip."</center>";
   }else{}
?>
```

Comment: Poderia colocar uma exemplo de texto que você coloca no `<textarea>`?

Comment: 192.168.45.1 e uma ferramenta para testar proxys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para tua lógica funcionar tive que fazer umas alterações. Tinha muitos erros que torna o motivo do problema um mistério. Mas, enfim, faça as seguintes alterações:

**Arquivo `index.html`**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title> Teste de IP's </title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.form.js"></script>
    <style>
        .red {
            color: brown;
        }
        .green{
            color: darkgreen;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="valida_ip" action="validaIP.php" method="post">
        <textarea name="ip" rows="10" cols="40"></textarea>
        <button type="submit">Enviar IP's</button>
    </form>
    <div id="reultados"></div>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#valida_ip').ajaxForm(function(data) {
                data = JSON.parse(data);
                $('#reultados').html('');
                if(data.ip != '') {
                    data.forEach(function (ip) {
                        $('#reultados').append('<li class="'+ip.class+'">'+ip.ip+'</li>');
                    });
                } else {
                    $('#reultados').append('<li class="'+data.class+'"> Erro ao ler informações no Textarea</li>');
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Arquivo `validaIP.php`**

```
<?php
if ($_POST['ip']) {
    $response = [];
    //gera um array de ip's, separando a string por virgula
    $ips = explode(',', $_POST['ip']);
    //$bin = substr($_POST['ip'], 0, 90);

    foreach ($ips as $ip) {
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "fonte dps testes");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "input_proxy=$ip");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
        $s = curl_exec($ch);
        $pop = preg_match('/<p>(.*)<\/p>/si', $s, $match);

        if ($pop) {
            array_push($response, [
                'class' => 'red',
                'ip' => '[ ' . $ip . ' #DIE_IPS ]'
            ]);
        } else {
            array_push($response, [
                'class' => 'green',
                'ip' => '[ ' . $ip . ' - #LIVE_IPS ]'
            ]);
        }
    }

    echo json_encode($response);
}else{
    echo json_encode([
            'class' => 'red',
            'ip' => ''
        ]);
}
```

Obs.: Este exemplo valida o IP sem atualizar a página. Outra coisa, coloque os ip's separados por vírgula no `<textarea>` para funcionar

Comment: obrigado porem o problema que enfrento é dar looping no código tipo: o php vai testar o proxy da primeira linha e depois printar o resultado, vai testar o da segunda e vai printar o resultado embaixo da primeira e assim vai printando um em baixo do outro testando todas as linhas ate não ter mais nenhuma e sem atualizar a pagina tudo no mesmo index 1 resultado em baixo do outro

Comment: Alterei a resposta conforme sua necessidade.